# How can I set up Timeshift to use a secondary hard drive for BTRFS backup?

Tags: backup, btrfs

I have been reading through quite a few alternatives including Timeshift and Snapper, and it doesn't seem like any of the BTRFS backup apps offer any ability to store BTRFS snapshots to a secondary or external hard drive.

Is there a possibility of doing this, or is this something intrinsic to the BTRFS format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Timeshift and Snapper use BTRFS snapshots as a means to retain the filesystem's state. Because BTRFS snapshots must be stored in the same filesystem which contains the subvolumes they are a snapshot of, snapshots cannot be used as true backups. By *true backup* I mean that the content is stored on a different, independent device. BTRFS filesystems can span multiple hard drives, but that's not a backup solution.

However, what you can do is use `btrfs-send` and `btrfs-receive` to backup the snapshots created by Timeshift or Snapper to a secondary device. Said device would need to have it's own independent BTRFS filesystem.

In short, no you cannot configure Timeshift nor Snapper to store "backups" on a separate device, but you can instead *send* those "backups" to a separate device.